# How can we add two "<td>" into "<tr>" using custom text

Tags: drupal-7

I have following data 
Mike Delonas,
Sean Delonas,
Gary Varvel,
Chip Varvel,
Adam Wasserman,
Daryl Cagle,
Dan Wasserman,
I am using custom text in Drupal back-end, I want to display this in  two "td" into "tr" using custom text.

Answer (score 0):

just try two td's like the code below:

```
<tr><td>Value1</td><td>Value2</td></tr>
```